# set value on sidebar

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having one google sheet having  more than 100 rows with column of "NAME, PLACE, PHONE". I want to change /correct the phone number on specific person Ex.John in the side bar (Form.html) and the correct place & phone number to be edit in that specific row of my google sheet "Phonelist". The code.gs  given below  which is  not working. Could you lease rectify the same?

```
function sidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Form").setTitle('Phone Details');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().sidebar(html);
  }

function result(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Phonelist");
  var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues(); 
 
  var name = form.name;
  var place = form.place;
  var phone = form.phone;
 
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
       if(data[i][1] == "John"){
          var result = [name,place,phone];
          ws.getRange(dat[i]).setValue(result); 
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you share a simplified spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what you exactly need. But there are some issues which are visible.

1. `ws.getRange(data[i])`is not valid. See [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column). You need a row *and* a column at least, and in your case also the number of columns since your are inserting a range. Currently you only have a column. The solution is `

```js
const startColumn = 1 // start at column A
const numberOfRows = 1 // update one row at a time
const numberOfColumns = result.length // this will be 3
ws.getRange(data[i], startColumn, numberOfRows, result.length)
  .setValues(result) // setValues is correct, setValue is incorrect
```

2. The second issue is that you said that **NAME** is in the first column, but your test is testing against the second column. Array start at 0, i.e. the first item is actual accessed by `[0]`. therefore your test `if(data[i][1] == "John")` actually checks if the second column **PLACE** is equal to "John". To fix this, replace the `[1]` with `[0]`, so:

```js
if(data[i][0] == "John")
```

3. The third issue is handled in the first answer. You are using `setValue()` which is only to be used to set one cell. But since you are setting a number of cells at one time, you should use `setValues()` instead.